# Hydronic baseboard heating and warm floors

Tags: heating, leak, baseboard, hydronic

I have hydronic baseboard heating throughout my house and have been having issues with air in the system. Since I've lived here (4.5 years) I've noticed that certain floor areas are warm where the pipes run (I'm assuming through the slab). It didn't occur to me until now that that could be an issue. Is this normal or could it be a slab leak? I should note that there is wood flooring over part of it and it is not warped or anything. I have no idea if this is normal so your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is air dissolved in water, as it's heated it tends to separate from the water.  There are air vents designed to let the air out, if you look at the pipes near the heat source, you should see them.  They might look like https://www.lowes.com/pd/Watts-Air-Vent/3308036.  Do you see these installed in your system?  Sometimes these leak water too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about a leak, check the pressure in your water heating. There should be a pressure gauge somewhere, probably on the boiler. If the pressure is in the normal range, then leaks are very unlikely. The "normal pressure" should be in the manual, or labeled on the gauge. You can always write down the value and check again a few days later. If it stays the same, there is no leak.

Normally a leak is pretty noticeable, since there should be no system in place to refill the circuit automatically, so the heating just stops working because there's not enough water.

> I've noticed that certain floor areas are warm where the pipes run (I'm assuming through the slab).

If the pipes were installed right in the slab without insulation, that's normal.